# Render a show view html with some restrictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view

I want to create a  random selection generator, which should be called using a button`<%= button_to("Randomize someting to do!", {:action => "random_task"}) %>`
this calls method `random task`

```
def random_task
  x = rand(Task.first.id..Task.last.id)
  @task = Task.find(x)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  random_task

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render @task}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

This is supposed to call back my view/random_task.html.erb

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name,:disabled=>true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.text_field, :category,:disabled=>true %>
  </div>/tasks/
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :points %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :points,:disabled=>true %>
  </div>
  <div class="rank_buttons"> 
     <%= link_to 'Vote up', :action => 'rate_up', :id => task.id %>
     <%= link_to 'Vote down', :action => 'rate_down', :id => task.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>  
  <% end %>
```

**Edit** Q: How do I call the right way the rendering form if it is written ok?

Comment: I don't understand the question, please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correcty, `random_task` is not calling `random_task.html.erb`, right?

`random_task` should be part of a controller. And `rand_task.html.erb` should be inside a folder with the same name as the controller in the views folder.

If `random_task` is in `randoms_controller.rb` for example, add `random_task.html.erb` to the following path: `views/randoms/`

then random_task should render the form you described.

I hope it helps